# How do i revert back to windows vista from ubuntu 12.10 on a Packard Bell laptop

Tags: restore, windows-vista

I bought the laptop on ebay and i dont have any discs for ubuntu or windows vista.  The stickers on the laptop indicate the factory settings as having vista installed.

Pressing Alt and F10 at startup to go into restore doesnt do anything.

Comment: If there is also no recovery partition then you have to get the install images or discs from somewhere to install the OS, legally of course. But installing Windows is mostly out of scope for this site. You should either contact the ebay seller, ebay customer support (if a working Windows was offered to you by the seller and he now refuses to comply) or the Microsoft customer support. Vista entered extended support on 10th April 2012 and will be supported until 11th April 2017. You may want to look out for a more recent version of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the hard drive was wiped clean before the Ubuntu install. If this is the case, it will not be possible to do a system restore as the recovery partition is non-existent.

The only way to get Vista back would be to order a new set of recovery disks. How easy this process is varies from supplier to supplier.

It looks like you will have to contact their customer support:
http://packard-bell-scandic.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16593

Be ready to read the device serial number, etc.

Comment: If you do not have the restore disk *but* still have the product key(on a sticker on the laptop, if still readable) you can download the ISO and use the key to install.  See [this page](http://www.askvg.com/direct-download-links-download-official-original-and-untouched-windows-vista-rtm-with-sp1-setup-files-32-bit-and-64-bit/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+AskVG+%28AskVG%29) It has the links on where to download and instructions on how to use them, also the duplicate link has info on a clean windows install in the first answer.

Comment: note on the above comment: The OP will not have to pay for new disks, or deal with the customer "support" from the manufacturer(I'm sure they will be less than helpful in this situation).  Either method will only work *if* you have the product key.  Your only option if the key is missing is to buy a new one at full price(I would guess around $100 US)